# How would I be able to open a new tab with Tampermonkey and be able to use Tampermonkey on that page too

Tags: tampermonkey

How would I be able to open a new tab with Tampermonkey and be able to use Tampermonkey on that page too?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use `window.open()` to open another page, if that page is also listed in `@include`, you're able to use Tampermonkey there too.